# How to force MySQL clients to send SSL certificate while logging in

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, openssl

I have a server on which I run PHP 7.2 (App Server) and another server with MySQL 8.0 (DB Server). My requirement is, no user should be able to login to MySQL from any server without providing a certificate. After doing some internet research, I have added the following configuration in the my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/path/to/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/path/to/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/path/to/server-key.pem
```

After this, when I check VARIABLES LIKE '%SSL%', I can see SSL is enabled. But from my App server terminal, am able to log in to MySQL on DB server with or without providing any certificate files. Even weirder thing is, When I try to connect from PHP using PDO or mysqli, am not able to connect. PDO is not giving any error, but in mysqli, am getting peer certificate CN=localhost does not match with expect CN . So, I think my traffic is SSL encrypted and is working the way https work, but authentication is not forcing users to use SSL certificate while logging in. What do I need to do to enforce client to send a certificate while logging in? Am using a user account which I created with `Require SSL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// following will force SSL connection
//alter user root@'%' REQUIRE  SSL; 

// following will force SSL connection with the certificate, else connection will be rejected
alter user root@'%' REQUIRE  X509;
```

**REQUIRE SSL** means one-way TLS authentication: the MySQL client must verify that the server's certificate is signed by a certificate authority it trusts. No client certificate is required. All traffic is fully encrypted.

**REQUIRE X509** means two-way TLS (mutual authentication): in addition to the above, the MySQL server must also trust the certificate authority that signed the client's certificate.

Both methods fully encrypt database traffic. The second strategy prevents a connection from someone who has the password but not a trusted certificate from connecting.